# How to make the dataframe can show this output with the JSON string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change the JSON structure to generate the expected output.

I don't want to achieve it with Python and Pandas.

Any idea about how to change the json format,

so that I can get the output by `pd.read_json(JSON_STR)` directly.

Thanks

## Current output of dataframe

```
json_str='''{  
   "2013-03-20_change_in_real_gdp":{  
      "2013":{  
         "upper_end_of_central_tendency":"2.8",
         "lower_end_of_range":"2.0"
      },
      "2014":{  
         "upper_end_of_central_tendency":"3.4",
         "lower_end_of_range":"2.6"
      }      
   },
   "2012-04-25_change_in_real_gdp":{  
      "2013":{  
         "upper_end_of_central_tendency":"7.7",
         "lower_end_of_range":"7.0"
      },
      "2014":{  
         "upper_end_of_central_tendency":"7.4",
         "lower_end_of_range":"6.3"
      }
    }
}'''

pd.read_json(json_str)
```

[image]

## This is the expected output from dataframe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working backwards, you can create your dataframe and then convert it to JSON to see the expected format.  When you try to convert it to JSON, you'll get an error because the measure index values are not unique.  After resetting the index, you'll get the following JSON.

```
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({2013: [2.8, 2, 7.7, 7], 
                   2014: [3.4, 2.6, 7.4, 6.3], 
                   'source': ['2013-03-20_change_in_real_gdp', 
                              '2013-03-20_change_in_real_gdp', 
                              '2012-04-25_change_in_real_gdp', 
                              '2012-04-25_change_in_real_gdp']}, 
                   index=['upper_end_of_central_tendency', 
                          'lower_end_of_range', 
                          'upper_end_of_central_tendency', 
                          'lower_end_of_range'])
df.index.name = 'measure'

>>> df.reset_index().to_json()

'{"measure": {"0":"upper_end_of_central_tendency",
              "1":"lower_end_of_range",
              "2":"upper_end_of_central_tendency",
              "3":"lower_end_of_range"},
  "2013": {"0":2.8,"1":2.0,"2":7.7,"3":7.0},
  "2014": {"0":3.4,"1":2.6,"2":7.4,"3":6.3},
  "source": {"0":"2013-03-20_change_in_real_gdp",
             "1":"2013-03-20_change_in_real_gdp",
             "2":"2012-04-25_change_in_real_gdp",
             "3":"2012-04-25_change_in_real_gdp"}}'"""
```